# how to display a mesh in front of my camera in Three.Js?

Tags: three.js

i want to show a mesh (like gunshot) in front of my perspective camera(with first person controls) i wrote this code in the render function of my page:

```
var pos = camera.position;
var rot = camera.rotation;
shot.rotation.x = rot.x;
shot.rotation.y = rot.y;
shot.rotation.z = rot.z;
shot.position.x = pos.x;
shot.position.y= pos.y;
shot.position.z = pos.z + 500;
```

if i just change the position of my camera its good, but if i change the camera's rotation i don't see the shot in front of that.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that you need to make the "shot" a child of the camera. It's not clear from your example whether you're doing that already, but this should make the shot move around with the camera properly.